# 'destructuring (Missing annotation)' source: 'flow'

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I am receiving the following error when destructuring in ES6.
I would like to know what is the right flow annotation to prevent this error.

> message: 'destructuring (Missing annotation)' source: 'flow'

```js
import React from 'react'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import Forecast from './Forecast'
import Map from './Map'

const Root = ({ store }) => ( //<<<< ERROR HERE
  <Provider store={store}>
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path='/' component={Forecast} />
    <Route exact path='/map' component={Map} />
  </Switch>
</Router>
  </Provider>
)
export default Root
```

```js
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk'
import promiseMiddleware from 'redux-promise-middleware'
import reducers from './reducers'

const store = createStore(reducers, applyMiddleware(
  thunkMiddleware,
  promiseMiddleware()
))

export default store
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decalre the `type` of `store`

ex:

```
const Root = ({ store } : {store : StoreType}) => {}
```

Comment: I'm a little confused by the ask.

Do you mean something like this:

const Root = ({ store } : {store: Object})